# MVC form validation with JQuery, problems with object

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

So I wanted to validate a form with JQuery validation, but it seems like JQuery doesnt like working with classes. Here is an example of what I've tried:

My js:

```
$('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            something: {
                required:true
            },
            'name.first': { //Between qoutes, because JS does not want to run without
                required:true
            },
            'name.last': {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });
```

My model:

```
public class myModal
{
    string something { get; set; }
    public name name { get; set; }
}

public class name
{
    string first { get; set; }
    string last { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Hanno

Comment: This looks good and should work fine. Can you show your view code?

Comment: Sorry! It works fine. Just forgot to include a JS file... I feel like such a noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stupid and forgot to include a JS file.